# sed command within a while loop doesn't write output

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have this input file

```
gb|KY798440.1|
gb|KY842329.1|
MG082893.1
MG173246.1
```

and I want to get all the characters that are between the "|" or the full line if there is no "|". That is a desired output that looks like

```
KY798440.1
KY842329.1
MG082893.1
MG173246.1
```

I wrote:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *\|* ]] ; then
    sed 's/.*\|\(.*\)\|.*/\1/' <<< $line >> output_file
    else echo $line >> output_file
     fi
done < input_file
```

Which gives me

```
empty line
empty line
MG082893.1
MG173246.1
```

(note: `empty line` means an actual empty line - it doesn't actually writes "empty line")

The sed command works on a single example (i.e. `sed 's/.*\|\(.*\)\|.*/\1/' <<< "gb|KY842329.1|"` outputs `KY842329.1`) but within the loop it just does a line return. The `else echo $line >> output_file` seems to work.

Comment: Why use the while/read loop instead of just letting sed process the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bare sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[^|]*|\||[^|]*$//g' file
```

Output:

```
KY798440.1
KY842329.1
MG082893.1
MG173246.1
```

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing. I thought I tried that... Thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
sed '/|/s/[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1/' input
```

or

```
awk 'NF>1 {print $2} NF < 2 { print $1}' FS=\| input
```

or

```
sed -e 's/[^|]*|//' -e 's/|.*//' input
```